# Integrate the following.

Tags: calculus, integration

Given

$$\dfrac{dN}{N}=4\pi\left(\dfrac{m}{2\pi K_b T}\right)^{3/2}v^2e^{mv^2/2K_bT}dv $$

How to integrate this from $v_0$ to infinity.?

Comment: Are you sure of this expression?  As stated, the integral will diverge.

Comment: Maybe that first v² should just be a v ?? (it would still diverge though)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want

$$\int_{v_0}^{\infty} dv \, v^2 \, e^{- a v^2} $$

where $a = m/(2 K_b T)$.  (I know this because I know this is the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution.)  Integrate by parts to get

$$-\frac{1}{2 a} \left [v \, e^{- a v^2} \right]_{v_0}^{\infty} + \frac{1}{2 a} \int_{v_0}^{\infty} dv \, e^{- a v^2}  = \frac{v_0}{2 a} e^{-a v_0^2} + \frac14 \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a^3}} \text{erfc}\left (\sqrt{a} v_0 \right )$$

Comment: what is erfc??....

Comment: @mathslover: complementary error function $$\text{erfc}{(x)} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_x^{\infty} dt \, e^{-t^2}$$